# How to write a filtered IObservableList

Tags: java, data-binding, filter, eclipse-databinding

From some API call, I am getting back an [**`IObservableList<E>`**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fdatabinding%2Fobservable%2Flist%2FIObservableList.html), from the Eclipse Databinding framework. I'd wish to derive another `IObservableList<E>` from this one according to some predicate defined on the element type `E`. The derived list should be dynamically updated according to changes in the original list.

How can I best implement that? I've considered subclassing `DecoratingObservableList`, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Of course, I could implement myself the whole `IObservableList` interface, but I was wondering if there were not other utility classes around that I could use.

Comment: People seeing your question based on the "java" tag will not realize what you are talking about. Mention Eclipse Databinding explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think extending `DecoratingObservableList` is a good start. I would also suggest concentrating on exactly the intended usage instead of immediately implementing the entire API. For example, do you need random-acces writing via `set`? If not, then don't bother implementing it. This covers a read-only view of a mutable `ObservableList`, mapping the change events of the decorated list to the appropriate change events on the filtered list:

```
public class FilteredObservableList<E> extends DecoratingObservableList
{
  private final IObservableList decorated;
  private final Predicate pred;
  private final List<E> filtered = new ArrayList();

  public FilteredObservableList(
      IObservableList decorated, Predicate pred, boolean disposeDecoratedOnDispose)
  {
    super(decorated, disposeDecoratedOnDispose);
    this.decorated = decorated;
    this.pred = pred;
    for (Object o : decorated) filtered.add(pred.eval(o)? (E) o : null);
  }

  @Override protected void handleListChange(ListChangeEvent event) {
    final List<ListDiffEntry> diffs = new ArrayList();
    final List<Integer> mapping = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    for (E e : filtered) mapping.add(e != null? i++ : i);
    event.diff.accept(new ListDiffVisitor() {
      @Override public void handleAdd(int index, Object element) {
        final boolean passes = pred.eval(element);
        filtered.add(index, passes? (E) element : null);
        final Integer outInd = mapping.get(index);
        mapping.add(index, outInd);
        if (passes) {
          diffs.add(new FilteredDiffEntry(outInd, true, element));
          for (int i = index + 1; i < mapping.size(); i++)
            mapping.set(i, mapping.get(i) + 1);
        }
      }
      @Override public void handleRemove(int index, Object element) {
        final boolean passes = filtered.get(index) != null;
        filtered.remove(index);
        final int outInd = mapping.get(index);
        mapping.remove(index);
        if (passes) {
          diffs.add(new FilteredDiffEntry(outInd, false, element));
          for (int i = index; i < mapping.size(); i++)
            mapping.set(i, mapping.get(i)-1);
        }
      }
    });
    if (!diffs.isEmpty()) {
      final ListDiffEntry[] difAry = diffs.toArray(new ListDiffEntry[diffs.size()]);
      fireListChange(new ListDiff() {
        @Override public ListDiffEntry[] getDifferences() { return difAry; }
      });
    }
  }

  public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
    getterCalled();
    final Iterator<E> it = decorated.iterator();
    return new ListIterator<E>() {
      E next;
      boolean nextReady;
      public boolean hasNext() {
        getterCalled();
        if (nextReady) return true;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
          next = it.next();
          if (next != null) { nextReady = true; break; }
        }
        return nextReady;
      }
      public E next() {
        getterCalled();
        if (hasNext()) { nextReady = false; return next; }
        else throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
      public void add(Object o) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public boolean hasPrevious() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public int nextIndex() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public E previous() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public int previousIndex() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
      public void set(Object o) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
    };
  }

  public interface Predicate { boolean eval(Object o); }

  private static final class FilteredDiffEntry extends ListDiffEntry {
    private final int pos;
    private final boolean isAdd;
    private final Object el;
    FilteredDiffEntry(int pos, boolean isAdd, Object el) {
      this.pos = pos; this.isAdd = isAdd; this.el = el;
    }
    @Override public int getPosition() { return pos; }
    @Override public boolean isAddition() { return isAdd; }
    @Override public Object getElement() { return el; }
  }

  @Override public Object move(int _, int __) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public Object remove(int _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public Object set(int _, Object __) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public void add(int _, Object __) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public boolean add(Object _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public boolean addAll(Collection _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public boolean addAll(int _, Collection __) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
  @Override public void clear() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public boolean remove(Object _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  @Override public boolean removeAll(Collection _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
  @Override public boolean retainAll(Collection _) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work as expected. For instance, it will still fire events when filtered out elements are added or removed from the wrapped list.

Comment: Of course, it only works for iteration. If you need add/remove, I'll see what I can do if I catch some time.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet But wait a second, how do you expect to block events from the wrapped list? If you registered a listener to the wrapped list and you add elements directly to it, it's going to fire events. If it is your requirement to automagically change the behaviour of the original list, and not to apply filtered behaviour on top of it, then this is not the solution for you. In fact, I have no idea how you will be able to achieve that.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Perhaps, depending on your exact usage, you could add/remove directly to the wrapped list, but you would definitely need to attach listeners to the decorating list. In such a case it could be arranged that the events are filtered appropriately.

Comment: I would of course attach them to the decorating list. But I think your solution forwards every event from the wrapped list to listeners of the decorating list.

Comment: Let's talk a bit about your intended usage. Now I'm thinking it might even be better to aim for the solution where you mutate the wrapped list directly and present its contents through the filtered list. Can you describe how you plan to put your filtered list to use?

Comment: I studied briefly the class hierarchy of `DecoratedObsrvableList` and didn't find evidence of it attaching itself as a listener of the wrapped list's events. Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: It happens in the implementation of the `handleListChange` method. Re: intended usage, it's simple: I get an unmodifiable observable list from somewhere, and I want to produce another observable list from that that acts exactly as the one I got in the first place, with certain elements being filtered out according to a predicate.

Comment: No, that's the opposite case: the events from the decorating list are being forwarded to the wrapped list. Nothing wrong with that. When the implementation grows and any of the mutating methods get implemented, it's going to need an according change.

Comment: The other question: and how exactly do you need that list to be used? For example, I don't think the method `add(int, Object)` makes sense for a filtered list.

Comment: I think it's not the opposing case. Here's part of the Javadoc: `Called whenever a ListChangeEvent is received from the decorated observable. By default, this method fires the list change event again`. Re: your other question: indeed, the new list should probably be read-only for client code.

Comment: Yes, I can see it now. It happens in `firstListenerAdded`. I've updated the code to disable that behavior. Now, no events will be propagated from the underlying list. How does that sound, for your use case?

Comment: It still sounds like a half-solution, since I do want events propagated as long as they are about elements not filtered out by the predicate.

Comment: I see. That's also not too hard to accomplish, but if you already think sharakan's solution to work better for you, go that way. One thing though: my proposal does not depend on constantly updating a cached filtered list, which relies on change events being propagated to the decorator. On the other hand, my approach would make `get(int)` less performant since it would always have to scan from the list start.

Comment: That's why I currently like your proposal a bit better :-)

Comment: Yep, hairy stuff, after all. The main difficulty is that you cannot escape holding a cache of the decorated list because at the moment you get change notification, the decorated list has already changed to the new state and you need the old state to calculate the diff mapping. See the updated code.

Comment: OK, time's up on the bounty, I’ll give you the points but I might follow up with a couple of remarks or questions :-)

Comment: It's been an amusing challenge so far (if I did it just for the 100-bounty, I wouldn't go to the trouble :), so I'll be there for your followups.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a read-only implementation.

A couple of caveats:

- This depends on the base DecoratingObservableList firing events on edits.
- The iterator won't be live if the decorated list changes after iterator creation time, it works like a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that way.  Arguably it should throw `ConcurrentModificationExceptions` there.

If it has to be writeable, can you define how you want to do index mapping, and perhaps specify whether you're going to allow non-unique items in the List?

```
package filteredobservablelist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.DecoratingObservableList;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.IObservableList;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.ListChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.ListDiff;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.ListDiffEntry;

public class FilteredObservableList extends DecoratingObservableList {

    private static final class FilteredListDiff extends ListDiff {

        private final List<ListDiffEntry> filteredDiffs;

        private FilteredListDiff(List<ListDiffEntry> filteredDiffs) {
            this.filteredDiffs = filteredDiffs;
        }

        @Override
        public ListDiffEntry[] getDifferences() {
            return filteredDiffs.toArray(new ListDiffEntry[filteredDiffs.size()]);
        }
    }

    public interface Predicate {

        boolean evaluate(Object element);

    }

    private final Predicate predicate;
    private List<Object> filteredList;

    public FilteredObservableList(IObservableList decorated, boolean disposeDecoratedOnDispose, Predicate predicate) {
        super(decorated, disposeDecoratedOnDispose);

        this.predicate = predicate;
        rebuildCache();
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleListChange(final ListChangeEvent event) {
        final List<ListDiffEntry> filteredDiffs = new ArrayList<ListDiffEntry>(event.diff.getDifferences().length);
        for (ListDiffEntry element : event.diff.getDifferences()) {
            if (predicate.evaluate(element.getElement())) {
                filteredDiffs.add(element);
            }
        }

        rebuildCache();

        if (!filteredDiffs.isEmpty()) {
            fireListChange(new FilteredListDiff(filteredDiffs));
        }
    }

    private void rebuildCache() {
        filteredList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Object element : getDecorated()) {
            if (predicate.evaluate(element)) {
                filteredList.add(element);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return filteredList.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection c) {
        return filteredList.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        getterCalled();
        return filteredList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        getterCalled();
        return filteredList.indexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        getterCalled();
        return filteredList.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    @Override
    public List subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        getterCalled();
        return this.filteredList.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public IObservableList getDecorated() {
        return (IObservableList) super.getDecorated();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return listIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator() {
        return this.listIterator(0);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator listIterator(int index) {
        getterCalled();

        final ListIterator iterator = filteredList.listIterator(index);

        return new ListIterator() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasPrevious() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.hasPrevious();
            }

            @Override
            public Object next() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.next();
            }

            @Override
            public int nextIndex() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.nextIndex();
            }

            @Override
            public Object previous() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.previous();
            }

            @Override
            public int previousIndex() {
                getterCalled();
                return iterator.previousIndex();
            }

            @Override
            public void add(Object o) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public void set(Object o) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Object move(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object set(int index, Object element) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good! I'll have a closer look at it shortly.

Comment: Actually I see two problems: 1. this code doesn't change the position of the filtered `ListDiffEntry`, so they're likely to turn out wrong in the filtered list; 2. for each single `ListChangeEvent`, you run through the whole decorated list again, whereas it could be simply modified from the obtained diffs for efficiency.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet 1. Whoops, didn't realize that structure had indexed fields.  I'll get to that this evening.  2. do you need it to be that performant?  It's doable, but is as difficult to get right as the mutators on the filtered list affecting the underlying.  The index mapping looks to be a pain.

Comment: Yes, index mapping is a pain, and that's what I'm trying to solve actually. I should maybe have mentioned that clearly in the question…

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the source code of [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) which has filterable, observable lists.

Comment: Since this is for Swing and the question is about JFace, this is hardly going to be useful.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Actually that's not correct. Glazed Lists can be used with SWT as well: http://hexapixel.com/2009/01/02/glazed-lists-swt-tables-true

Comment: @ulmangt Hmm... "as we use SWT we have to do pretty much all the work ourselves"

Comment: Maybe an implementation of `IObservableList` on top of a concrete class provided by GaledLists?

Comment: Yes, having looked at that page this seems like a way to get a filtered list -- but if, as you said, you need to decorate an existing `ObservableList`, then it's a poor choice.